# Javascript, How to show two value into same input type text field?

Tags: javascript

I want to show 10 20 in single input type text, but below option is not working. Can any one help me

Javascript:-

```
var a = 10;
var b = 20;

document.getElementById("current").value = a , b;
```

HTML:-

```
<input type="text" id="current">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("current").value = a + " " + b;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `document.getElementById("current").value= a +" " + b;`

Answer (score 1):

According to your question simply use following to concat two values.

```
var a = 10;
var b = 20;

document.getElementById("current").value = a+" "+b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var a = 10;
var b = 20;
document.getElementById("current").value = ""+a +" "+b;
```

Hope it Helps!